# How to pass parameters to a variadic function, dynamically?

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider some variadic function `foo(int...args)`.

I want to be able to call it dynamically. That is, the parameters will be given to me through some simple data structure like an array/vector etc (doesn't really matter).

How can I pass them to call `foo()`?

Comment: these C-styled variadic functions are highly error prone. Have a look at C++11's variadic templates. Still, you should use iterators.

Comment: You have to runtime dispatch until a given size...

Comment: Why not `template <typename InputIt> foo(InputIt first, InputIt last)`?

Comment: What's not really clear is whether the number of arguments being passed is known at compile time(array) or runtime (vector). Maybe if you could be specific about whether the parameters will be given via a `std::array` or a `std::vector` we could help?

Comment: @iehrlich, I actually came across this, but the same question is applied here. How would you call the `foo()` you have defined?

Comment: Actually, it could be pretty much straight forward using an `std::array` or an `std::vector` instead (as @NirFriedman stated)

Comment: @Covvar Did you define `foo`, or is it not under your control? And to be clear, you are talking C style variadic, right?

Comment: can you please clarify the question? If you dont really need the function to be variadic, but you simply need to pass a variable number of parameters, then the given answer is a perfect fit, but whats the point of the variadic function in the first place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*NOTE: Based on the OP's comment, I think that using iterators over source collections is a viable option here.*

Consider using the same trick as is commonly used in standard library, for example [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort).

```
template<typename InputIt>
void foo(InputIt begin, InputIt end)
{
    for (InputIt it = begin; it != end; ++it)
    {
        // do whatever you need with (*it);
    }
}
```

and then call it like this:

```
std::vector<int> myVector(1, 2, 3);
foo(myVector.begin(), myVector.end());
```

or, as per [@YSC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5470596/ysc),

```
std::vector<int> myVector(1, 2, 3);
foo(std::begin(vector), std::end(vector));
```

There are a couple of things to keep in mind. If you want to use this approach, your code needs to meet the following requirement: any logic you place in `foo` should be applicable to the value_type of the source collection. For example, if you explicitly convert `(*it)` to integer inside `foo`, while there's no such conversion for the `value_type` of the source vector, the compilation will fail.

However, this approach comes with some benefits. You can use this implementation with either `std::vector<T>` or `std::array<T>` right away. If you want to also use it with associative structures like std::unordered_map, it'll be a little more tricky, but the idea is the same.

Comment: You don't really need to make a copy of begin at all, the more idiomatic approach is to simply increment `begin` directly (note that it was passed by value so you already have your own copy).

Comment: imho this is a solution, but strictly speaking it doesnt answer the question, but instead silently assumes that passing the parameters to a variadic function isnt an option at all

Comment: `foo(std::begin(myVector), std::end(myVector));` would allow `myVector` to be, for instance, a `int[]`.

Comment: @NirFriedman true. However, I somehow dislike `while (++begin != end)` constructs. My personal approach is to start with more straightforward (but maybe less effective) code, and optimize it as needed.

Comment: @iehrlich I didn't say anything about a while loop, you just leave the first clause blank. `for (; begin != end; ++begin)`. This is perfectly idiomatic when loop variable is already initialized. See "Possible Implementation" http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find.

Comment: @NirFriedman I see, thanks :)

Comment: @YSC thanks for the note, added it to the answer!

Comment: @tobi303 I was particularly answering the *"I want to be able to call it dynamically. That is, the parameters will be given to me through some simple data structure like an array/vector"* part of the question. Honestly, that's how variadic functions are internally implemented in languages like Lua or python :)

Comment: yeah I think you answered the real question, while the question about variadic fucntions was a xy-problem. I was just thinking that someone might need to call a variadic function (because the function itself cannot be changed) then they wont find the answer here. Dont get me wrong, imho your answer is fine but the question should be made more clear. As it stands now it isnt obvious whether the variadic function is really the problem or part of a mislead solution

Comment: @NirFriedman You're making the compiler's job by doing this kind of optimization, and you trade a few keystrokes against a slightly unusual for-loop which may bring amazement. And you don't want to draw the reader's attention on an unimportant bit of code.